Why does my remove vowel function not work?
I'm trying to make a function that takes in a string and removes all vowels. I'm pretty sure the code should work, but when I go to use the function it just return the same string.
I've tried using multiple or statements, and I'm am now onto using a list of the vowels and iterating through the list while comparing it to the current char in the string. Still, it returns the unchanged string.
def remove_vowels(string):
    newStr = string.lower()
    for i in range(len(newStr)):
        if(newStr[i] == ("a" or "e" or "i" or "o" or "u")):
            newStr = newStr.replace(newStr[i], "")
    return newStr

print(remove_vowels("watermelon"))


"it just return the same string" - No, it raises IndexError: string index out of range. In the future, please make a [mre].

BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and see [ask] for more tips.

Your code does not have the fault you say it has. When I run it, it gives me an error. Your question should either be about the error or you are running different code.

Related: How to remove items from a list while iterating?

@quamrana OP's not using a list, so how is that duplicate target helpful? And why did you remove the other one? OP also has a problem with how or works.

Related: String removal in for loop

@wjandrea: The original duplicate does not apply to the specific code that the OP shows. Your last suggestion is a better dupe. I'll add that.

@quamrana "The original duplicate does not apply to the specific code that the OP shows" - How so?

@wjandrea: The OP has code like: x == (a or b or c), which translates to: (x == a). The dupe has code like: x == a or b or c which roughly translates to True.
